# Oracle SQL MAX and GROUP BY Costs too Much Lines of Code

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, aggregate

I have this long query, where I want to fetch some data about employees:

```
SELECT e.id,
e.emp_number,
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MONTH/YYYY') "GREGORIAN",
to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYYY','nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah''') HIJRI,
ba.acc_number "Account Number"
to_char(c.id) "National ID",
en.name

FROM
  relationships r,
  rel_actions ra,
  actions a,
  payrolls p,
  emp_names en,
  citizenships c,
  pay_methods pm,
  bank_accounts ba,
  assignments as,
  emp e

WHERE r.id = ra.id
AND r.id=pm.id
AND as.id = e.id
AND r.id = e.id
AND en.id = e.id
AND en.NAME_TYPE ='GLOBAL'
AND a.action_type  = 'T'
AND a.id = ra.id
AND a.id = p.id
and c.id = e.id
and ba.id=pm.id
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN ba.start_date AND ba.end_date 
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN p.effective_start_date AND p.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN en.effective_start_date AND en.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN e.effective_start_date AND e.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN pm.effective_start_date AND pm.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN as.effective_start_date AND as.effective_end_date
AND  as.assignment_type = 'E'
AND SYSDATE BETWEEN as.effective_start_date AND  as.effective_end_date

ORDER BY e.emp_number
```

the result of this query will be something like this :

```
emp_number      account_number      name      national_id       gregorian         hijri           

1               6456                john      ^*&$^**$^**       6/12/2022         12/5/1444
1               6456                john      ^*&$^**$^**       6/12/2022         12/5/1444
2               4121                Mathew    %&#%^%&%&%^       6/12/2022         12/5/1444
2               4121                Mathew    %&#%^%&%&%^       6/12/2022         12/5/1444
```

taking the first 2 rows for example, they have different `effective_date`, so I want to fetch the row that have the newest `effective_date`:

```
and a.effective_date in (
select effective_Date from pay_payroll_actions 
where  a.effective_date BETWEEN ba.start_date AND ba.end_date 
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN p.effective_start_date AND p.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN en.effective_start_date AND en.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN e.effective_start_date AND e.effective_end_date
AND a.effective_date BETWEEN pm.effective_start_date AND pm.effective_end_date
AND a.action_type  = 'T'
AND a.id = ra.id
AND a.id = p.id
    
)

GROUP BY e.id, e.emp_number,
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MONTH/YYYY'),
to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYYY','nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah'''),
ba.acc_number ,
to_char(c.id),
en.name
```

my question is, do I really need to apply all related conditions in the sub-query in order to get the same effective dates resulted from the main query?
and if yes, its too long, is there a way to shorten this? thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't including the effective date in your select list, so why does it matter which of the duplicate rows you eliminate - if all the columns you are selecting are the same, why not just use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: because it may matter in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the duplicate rows using `row_number ()`

```
 WITH cte 
 AS
 (SELECT e.id,
  e.emp_number,
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MONTH/YYYY') "GREGORIAN",
  to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYYY','nls_calendar=''arabic hijrah''') HIJRI,
   ba.acc_number "Account Number"
   to_char(c.id) "National ID",
   en.name,

   row_number() over (partition BY e.id,
  e.emp_number,ba.acc_number,c.id,en.name ORDER BY a.effective_date desc) AS dup_count
     FROM your_query)
     SELECT * FROM cte WHERE dup_count = 1;
```

OR Since you are already checking the dates between condition in your main query ,you can refine your sub query to

```
 and a.effective_date in (
 select effective_Date from pay_payroll_actions py
 where a.id=py.id
 )
```

Comment: good turn around the solution, but its not perfect as it depends on the order of the resulted rows, its not guaranteed solution